# Disabling action but keep menu enabled

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Here is how I create menu on Action item.

```
QAction * menuHolder = new QAction("Holder");
menuHolder->setMenu(new QMenu());
menuHolder->menu()->addAction(new QAction("Menu item"));
```

My problem is how to disable `menuHolder` but keep menu associated to the action enabled(arrow [image]near `menuHolder` should still be enabled).
I've tried something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
menuHolder->setEnabled(false);
menuHolder->menu()->setEnabled(true); ?
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after comments:**

It seems you're looking for a solution for a problem you don't have. You could prefectly handle that scenario as many many others applications do:

If the user click to `save` and don't have permissions just notify about that, and if you want, you could explain that he/she needs to save the file with another name.

In most of applications the user will look for `File -> Save as` for doing that.

So, separate the actions, the way you are trying to do alse can confuse the user and never find the action `Save as`, sice is under a disabled icon.

Comment: No. `menuHolder` should be disabled, but arrow and actions in menu should be still enabled.

Comment: @Edward What are you trying to achive then? Whats the real purpose for disabling `menuHolder` adn keep the arrow?

Comment: Idea is following: `menunHolder` is Save action, items in menu is "Save  as", "Export", etc. Save action should be disabled because user does not have permissions to modify original file, but he's able to save editing file with different name, export, etc.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't fix my problem. I don't need to improve user experience, that's not my job. I just need to implement functionality described in PRD. So i need just disable action with menu attached, but keep menu enabled. Is it possible in Qt?